# GitLab CI/CD pipeline, deploy to Windows Server

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Using GitLab Runner I have on Linux, I am trying to connect to a Windows Server and run some basic commands there such as `git pull`.

Does GitLab runner provide any capabilities for accessing windows server?

What other options are there to get such requirement done?

Comment: Maybe gitlab runner for windows will do the job https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/windows.html

Comment: I assume this is to execute the runner on a Windows machine, however in my scenario, I already have a GitLab server with runner on a Linux machine and I am try to access the windows machine to run some commands.

Comment: I think its just what runners do. When you install runner on windows machine then it may be invoked from linux build server and do some commands remotely (on Windows). What command do you need to run?

Comment: I am trying to access the windows server from GitLab CI pipeline, and run commands like "git pull"

Comment: @Benjamin I've the same problem, connecting from a linux environment to a windows 2019 server. Did you manage to connect to windows?

Comment: @tecmec, I highly encourage you to find a different alternative. GitLab CI runner is not designed for this purpose, installing OpenSSH on windows is very hacky approach and you don't have the same capabilities as you have when connecting a to Linux endpoint.

Comment: I think GL runner does not come with any utility at all; it's just an GL agent that will perform any native commands on its host machine and send the results back to your GL instance. It's just a job executor; you need to install beforehand any tools that you need for your job

Comment: @EmersonCardoso, that's the most accurate comment so far. Could you please put this as an answer ? I can understand what you mean, but feel free to elaborate further.

Comment: @Benjamin did you figure it out? i am facing the same situation

Comment: @FinnFrotscher, things might have changed since the day I posted this question ( I really doubt so), but as of that time there was no official way of connecting to a windows server without going through so much hacks. even installing openssh and connecting to it was not as straight forward as how you can connect to a Linux machine.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a few options

- install openssh and configure server on your windows machine/vm and connect from your gitlab runner with ssh ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse )
- ( as Wojciech Wirzbicki commented) install a gitlab runner instance on windows. https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/windows.html . I think this option more secure and easy win
- connect to windows server with winrm

Comment: The first option seemed more realistic than any other. Second option is totally invalid, because I am not trying to have GitLab Runner on the windows Machine, Rather I am trying to connect to Windows machine FROM gitlab Runner.

Comment: @Benjamin How did You finally solve that problem? I force similar issue and even know how to start..

Comment: @bartekch, I did not find an out of the box solution. I end up installing openSSH on the windows machine and connecting to the machine via SSH. BUT keep in mind it was a very hacky approach which took me a long time to do. I still believe there is a better way of doing this.